# How to force a database connection to fail in the middle of a dataflow task

Tags: ssis

A have four dataflow tasks in a sequence container running concurrently connecting to the same Oracle database.  That is there is no little green line connecting the four dataflow tasks to force them to execute in order.

Very infrequently while executing the four dataflow tasks, the obdc connections to the Oracle fails.

One or more dataflows fail to complete.  Note the usual OnError handler never got hit.

I can handle that scenario and fail gracefully.

But how do I test it?

The package is installed and executed on a server.  I'd like to be able to forcibly kiil the odbc connections while the package is running and pulling data from the Oracle database.

I do not have access to Oracle to kill the appropriate process in a similar fashion as I would within Sql Server Management Studio.

The closest I can think of doing is tweaking the connection string which in set up as a Package Configuration in a Sql Server database so that it fails to connect to a random dummy server name.  Not quite the same thing but at least the dataflow will fail.  It just wont fail for the exact reason I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to forcibly kill things, I would use a SSiS Transaction, so if one fails, everything rolls back. To do this, do the following:

1. Make sure MSDTC is running
2. Set TransactionOption = Supported at the package level
3. Set TransactionOption = Required at the Sequence Container level
4. Set TransactionOption = Supported on the Data Flow tasks

Now, they should all succeed or all rollback.

Comment: I was more looking to test that the process can handle the sudden loss of connection.  I can already allegedly handle the failure but I want to confirm it does actually handle the error.

Comment: @BlackMael  In that case, set one of the data flow tasks to ForceExecutionResult = Failure. Again, this will not forcibly kill the connection, but the task will report to SSIS that it failed, even if it should have succeeded